# Twilio : How to grant access to camera once for all?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I have a meeting app using Twilio Video.

The app has a requirement such that when a user wants to join a room, it's not immediate. That means : A user sends a request to the app server to join, immediately he will see his local webcam, then he will wait for sometime until the server responds with a token to join the room. It may be 10 or 20 minutes.

The communication between the client and the server is done through WebSockets.

Here is the process :

**Step 1:**
Client sends a request to the app server to join a room

**Step 2:**
Request access and show the client local camera as follows :

```
// Get the track from twilio
const Track = await Twilio.Video.createLocalVideoTrack();

// Add track to HTML        
LocalMediaContainer.appendChild(Track.attach());
```

**Step 3:**
Client waits for the server to respond  (let's say 10 minutes)

**Step 4:**
The server responds with the token to join Twilio video room

**Step 5:**
Client joins room using the token sent by the server as follows

```
Twilio.Video.connect(Token, { name:RoomName }).then(room => {
    console.log('Successfully joined a Room');

    room.on('participantConnected', participant => {
      console.log('A remote Participant connected ');
    });
  }, error => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to Room');
  });
```

The process works fine. The problem I'm getting however, is that in Step 5, when the client is trying to join a room, twilio asks him again to grant access to camera.

Basically, even though the access has already been granted, the method **Twilio.Video.connect** asks again for access.

I was wondering if there is a way to use the authorization previously granted to use the camera and avoid asking for it again if it has already been granted.

Thanks
Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you call `Twilio.Video.connect` you can pass an array of tracks with the user's media that you already have.

```js
Twilio.Video.connect(Token, { name: RoomName, tracks: [VideoTrack, AudioTrack] }).then(...);
```

This uses your existing tracks instead of making a new permissions request to `getUserMedia`.